# Can't log in, seemingly locked out of home directory

Tags: files, fedora, permissions, login, home

I just switched over from Kubuntu to Feodra KDE Spin. Now, I have an LVM setup where my home partition is on its own volume. I created a user with the same username as the one I had in the last distro. I was dismayed to find out that I couldn't log in. The screen just went blank, then I saw a blinking cursor, and then I was bounced back to the login screen. I tried to login from a tty, which worked, but I got this wonderful message:

```
-- user: /home/user: change directory failed: Permission denied
```

Okay. So I logged in as root and tried to chown everything back to `user`. Nothin' goin'. I chmoded my /home/user directory. Still nothing. I'm officially at a loss as to what I should try next, and I thought you fine folks might help. Here's some information for you:

```
id -u user 
1000

stat /home/user/
  File: '/home/user/'
  Size: 4096            Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   directory
Device: fd02h/64770d    Inode: 11272193    Links: 22
Access: (0700/drwx------)  Uid: ( 1000/user)   Gid: ( 1000/user)
Context: system_u:object_r:unlabeled_t:s0
Access: 2017-06-16 19:42:02.224062623 -0400
Modify: 2017-06-16 19:42:00.651082621 -0400
Change: 2017-06-16 19:42:00.651082621 -0400
 Birth: -
```

It all looks good to me, but what do I know? Strangely enough, when I am logged in as `user`, I can `cd` into that directory with no issues.

Comment: You might, as root, do `restorecon -Rv /home`. The context should be `user_home_dir_t` I believe.

Comment: Do I really do that on `/home` or do I do it on `/home/user`?

Comment: The recursive (-R) parameter will update everything in `/home`. You can also specify `/home/user` if you believe other directories in `/home` are correct. Given that some directories in the user's home dir also have contexts (e.g., .ssh is ssh_home_t), I would keep the `-R` regardless.

Comment: By jove, that did it. Write an answer and I'll accept it. I've never really messed with SE Linux, so I would probably have never ever guessed this would be a solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based upon the OP's information (which, btw, was excellent for the question), the SELinux context was incorrect. In the OP's question, the Context showed as:

`Context: system_u:object_r:unlabeled_t:s0`

However, a home directory should have `user_home_dir_t`.

To resolve the situation, running `restorecon -Rv /home` (using /home ensures that home directories for other users are updated; one could fix just the particular users's home dire by `restorecon -Rv /home/user`) will adjust the situation. The result should be similar to:

```
File: ‘/home/user’
Size: 4096          Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   directory
Device: fd00h/64768d    Inode: 18642668    Links: 16
Access: (0700/drwx------)  Uid: ( 1000/ user)   Gid: ( 1000/ user)
Context: unconfined_u:object_r:user_home_dir_t:s0      <-- THE CONTEXT
Access: 2017-06-16 19:10:34.914968689 -0600
Modify: 2017-06-16 18:30:31.135767008 -0600
Change: 2017-06-16 18:30:31.135767008 -0600
Birth: -
```

Using the `-R` would also ensure that directories in the `/home/user` were properly adjusted. For example the `.ssh` directory has a context of `unconfined_u:object_r:ssh_home_t:s0`.